# Bootstrap collapse not working on one server

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, twitter-bootstrap-3

Working on a Rails 4 project deployed on Heroku. I am using bootstrap and the collapse functionality. What bugs me is on my development and my test server(also on Heroku) my collapse works fine. But on my production the collapse is not working. I pushed the exact same commits. I checked the jquery loaded on both sites and it is the same. As far as i know the only difference is a lot more data in the production. But could that cause this not working?

Comment: In my experience, there may be several reasons, 1.jquery version is too low. 2. Load `jquery.js` after loading `bootstrap.min.js` (bootstrap depends on jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using strings for my div ids and on my produciton these included whitespaces...Mystery solved